# Is the sequence $s_n:=f_{n,n} $ where $f_{0,n}=f_{n,0}= n!$ and $f_{m,n} = f_{m-1,n}+ f_{m,n-1} + f_{m-1,n-1}$ P-recursive?

Tags: recurrences

Is the sequence $s_n:=f_{n,n} $ where $f_{0,n}=f_{n,0}= n!$ and $f_{m,n} = f_{m-1,n}+ f_{m,n-1} + f_{m-1,n-1}$ P-recursive?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-recursive_equation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_function

$a(n):=f_{n,n}$

$$0 = (310000 - 87575*n^2 + 25110*n^3 - 2015*n^4)*a(n-6)  + (-3082368 + 190872*n + 1063326*n^2 - 378291*n^3 + 37173*n^4)*a(n-5) + (8418604 - 1615685*n - 3834272*n^2 + 1836495*n^3 - 232486*n^4)*a(n-4) + (-4087868 + 3360702*n + 3358400*n^2 - 2858550*n^3 + 517914*n^4)*a(n-3) + (-3408770 - 992468*n + 1472981*n^2 + 176556*n^3-157931*n^4)*a(n-2)+(582108 + 205634*n - 541582*n^2 + 120633*n^3 + 12993*n^4)*a(n-1) + (-3362 - 20943*n + 37298*n^2 - 12993*n^3)*a(n) $$ (Conjectured)

Comment: What is a P-recursive sequence?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-recursive_equation

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_function

Comment: Perhaps, this might help with a few pointers: https://mathoverflow.net/q/39287. In your case, the bivariate generating function is $$\frac{(1-x)e^y+(1-y)e^x-1}{1-x-y-xy}.$$

Comment: In Alex's comment, $e^x$ should be $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n! x^n$. So there won't be an explicit formula for the diagonal, but it will be D-finite, since the diagonal of a D-finite series in two variables is D-finite.

Comment: @Alexander Burstein  And what is the recurrence?

Comment: I think I found it, thank you

Comment: @IraGessel Ira, indeed, I accidentally put $n!$ in the denominator by force of habit.